# How was Eric Brown allowed to act in the movie "Private Lessons"(1981)?

Tags: casting, private-lessons

[Eric Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Brown_%28actor%29) was only fifteen years of age when he acted in the erotic film ["Private Lessons"(1981)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Lessons_%281981_film%29).

How was he allowed to act in that film when he was only 15?

What was the opinion of Eric Brown's parents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a partial answer present through Imdb source.

> While most of the movie was filmed in the Phoenix, Arizona area the
>   production had to cross the border into New Mexico to film the love
>   scenes as the age of consent in Arizona is 18 and in New Mexico it is
>   16. (Source: [Imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082948/trivia))

Comment: So that's how they got around the age-of-consent problem, but aren't there laws preventing people under 18 from starring in adult scenes? How'd they get around *that* restriction?